# Calculating SPL from voltage output of a microphone with MAX4466 amplifier

Tags: sound, level, pressure

I'm using [Electret Microphone Amplifier - MAX4466 with Adjustable Gain](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1063) and I'm getting the output voltage ranging from 1.5V to 3V (which, to my knowledge, is already amplified by MAX4466). I know that the sensitivity of the microphone is -44dB @ 1kHz. It is also stated on the mentioned product page that the gain can be adjusted from 25x to 125x by adjusting the trimmer pot on the back of the breakout as needed.

[image: Max4466 Mic Amp Breakout with Trimmer Pot to Adjust the Gain]

I'd like to know a way to figure out the op-amp gain and ultimately, calculate SPL dB (Sound Pressure Level) from the measured voltage. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
[image: Typical Application Circuit]

Comment: This is the true Adafruit product schematic https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/4521

Answer (score 4):

Microphone sensitivity is quoted at

> -44 ±2 dB, f = 1KHz, 1Pa 0dB = 1V/Pa

This means that for 1 Pa RMS sound pressure on the microphone you get -44 dBV RMS at 1kHz. Still confused?

Well, -44 dBV translates to \$10^{-44/20}\$ volts = 6.31 mV RMS and 1 Pa translates to a decibel sound pressure level of 94 dB SPL.

So your microphone produces a 1kHz sinewave of amplitude 6.31 mV RMS when subjected to a SPL sinewave of 94 dB.

As for the gain of the Maxim circuit, without a circuit diagram I can't help you any further.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a circuit diagram that I hope what you asked for.

Comment: Mid-band gain (1 kHz) is about 11. The upper -3dB point is about 16 kHz (high frequency) and the lower one about 16 Hz.

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much for your time. Those are the ideal/calculated values, aren't they? Is there a way to measure the actual gain? And also, I'd like to know where you got those values from.

Comment: @J.Jay the mid-band gain will be as accurate as the resistor tolerances. If you want to measure it, use a signal generator and an oscilloscope but if the resistors are 1% or better then there is no point because the visual accuracy of the scope screen is probably worse than 2%.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. If it's not too much to ask, may I know how you got those numbers?

Comment: What numbers? The ones in my answer or the 3dB points?

Comment: The **11x** for the mid-band gain in your answer. The [product page](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1063) says that the gain can be adjusted between 25x and 125x.

Comment: I think you need to dig deeper. The schematic shown in your question HAS a mid-band gain of 11. If adafruit says differently they are either wrong or they use a different circuit. Also to consider is this - how do they say it can be adjusted - maybe it's by component replacement? I can't answer that so, you need to do your homework and think out of the box a bit more. As far as I'm concerned THIS question is answered. Also I see in your question that you say the gain adjustment is by a trimmer - do you see a trimmer in your schematic? No, ergo - you have shown the wrong schematic.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to all these. I've added a new picture of the breakout. Still, I'd like to know where you get the gain "11x" from. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Gain of a non-inverting op-amp amplifier = 1 + R2/R1. R2 is 100k and R1 is 10k hence mid-band gain = 1 + 10 = 11. At the higher frequencies the upper 3 dB point is when the 100pF has 100k impedance = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi F C}\$ or F = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi RC}\$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications

Comment: @Andyaka I've made a similar question recently and you've pretty much answered it here, but could you clarify the relationship between the output in volts and corresponding dB SPL input? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/227208/understanding-microphone-sensitivity

Comment: OP: the diagram you add is NOT the actual diagram; it's just an example on the datasheet. @Andyaka The adjustability is provided by a TC33X-2-104E. In actual design, R1 is 1K, R2 is 22K + [100 Ohm, 100,000 Ohm].

Comment: @XiHan I don't know how to respond to your comment.

Comment: @Andyaka This is Adafruit's schematic, with the trim potentiometer, that according to Adafruit lets the user adjust gain from 25 x to 125 x with a 270° turn https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/4521

Comment: @Systembolaget I have no idea why that might be relevant to the answer. It's down to the op to provide the correct circuit and notify me. This question is from 2016 so, it's low on my list of work in progress.

Comment: @Andyaka Well, the OP did not find the correct schematic and XiHan also failed to link to it. Because I have a similar problem (how to incorporate amplifier gain, etc.), and because this is a popular hobbyist device, I find it prudent to link to the correct information here for the benefit of others who get here, just like I did.

Comment: Please link it directly below the question and not here. That makes a whole lot more sense.